# Concatenating array elements into a one string in for loop using awk

Tags: awk, vcf-variant-call-format

I am working on a variant calling format (vcf) file, and I tried to show you guys what I am trying to do:

Input:

```
1       877803  838425  GC      G
1       878077  966631  C       CCACGG
```

Output:

```
1       877803  838425  C       -
1       878077  966631  -       CACGG
```

In summary, I am trying to delete the first letters of longer strings.

And here is my code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } /#/ {next}
{
    m = split($4, a, //)
    n = split($5, b, //)
    x = "-"
    delete y
    if (m>n){
        for (i = n+1; i <= m; i++) {
            y = sprintf("%s", a[i])
        }
        print $1, $2, $3, y, x
    }
    else if (n>m){
        for (j = m+1; i <= n; i++) {
            y = sprintf("%s", b[j]) ## Problem here
        }
        print $1, $2, $3, x, y
    }
}' input.vcf > output.vcf
```

But,

1. I am getting the following error in line 15, not even in line 9

`awk: cmd. line:15: (FILENAME=input.vcf FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array y in a scalar context`

2. I don't know how to concatenate array elements into a one string using awk.

I will be very happy if you guys help me.

Merry X-Mas!

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, can't you just use `$4=substr($4,2)` (etc)  ? Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS="\t" 'function trim(s) { return (length(s) == 1 ? "-" : substr(s, 2)); } {$4 = trim($4); $5 = trim($5)} 1' file

1   877803  838425  C   -
1   878077  966631  -   CACGG
```

More readable form:

```sh
awk -v OFS="\t" 'function trim(s) {
   return (length(s) == 1 ? "-" : substr(s, 2))
}
{
   $4 = trim($4)
   $5 = trim($5)
} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk's substr function to process the 4th and 5th space delimited fields:

```
awk '{ substr($4,2)==""?$4="-":$4=substr($4,2);substr($5,2)==""?$5="-":$5=substr($5,2)}1' file
```

If the string from position 2 onwards in field 4 is equal to "", set field 4 to "-" otherwise, set field 4 to the extract of the field from position 2 to the end of the field. Do the same with field 5. Print lines modified or not with short hand 1.